# Visio VBA Adding Bold Text to Shape Comment

Tags: vba, visio

I am writing a macro to read in rows from an excel file, create rectangles, auto-connect the rectangles, and add information to the connector screen tip from the Excel file. This is the section of code where I add the comment to the connector...

```
'Auto connect shapes
Dim vsoConnectorShape As Visio.Shape
Set vsoConnectorShape = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Dynamic connector")
vsoConnectorShape.Text = xlWsh.Range("A" & r)

'Populate screen tip with info from Excel
Dim PrintString As String

PrintString = "Interface #: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("A" & r) + vbCrLf & _
              "Descr: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("B" & r) + vbCrLf & _
              "Cat: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("C" & r) + vbCrLf & _
              "Info Obj: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("D" & r) + vbCrLf & _
              "Src: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("E" & r) & _
              " Tgt: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("F" & r) + vbCrLf & _
              "New/Changed: " + "   " + xlWsh.Range("G" & r)

vsoConnectorShape.Cells("Comment").FormulaU = "=""" & PrintString & """"
```

How do I make the labels in the comment (Interface #:, Descr:, Cat:, Info Obj, etc...) **bold** and leave the rest of the text as is?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: No, this was a request from a System Integrator I was working with but after looking around it seemed like any viable solutions were not worth the time because I had to rush through the project and clip non-essential parts. If you have a solution I'd like to see it though.

Comment: If it was still something you were needed to solve I was going to put a bounty on it.  We'll save that for more urgent issues.

Comment: I know this is an ancient question, but I just solved a similar problem by using the `EventDblClick` cell formula to launch a subroutine that populates a text rectangle in the lower left corner of the drawing and then hides it after a set amount of time. This allows me some control over the text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as far as I'm aware.  Comment text is not formatable.